# Unable to display a jquery plugin's colorbox in a wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, colorbox

After checking a few related questions in stackoverflow and wordpress.stackexchange.com, I am not being able to display a colorbox in my wordpress site, in localhost, when I add the code below to the  of my header.php:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="localhost/apoise/wp-content/themes/virality/colorbox-master/example1colorbox.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="localhost/apoise/wp-content/themes/virality/colorbox-master/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $.colorbox({
        width: 500,
        height: 600,
        href: "#colorbox_text"
        )};
    });
</script>

</head>
```

In a post, I placed the html:

```
<div id="colorbox_test" style="border: 1px solid black">
    <p> This is supposed to display when the colorbox function is called </p>
</div>
```

No box is displaying when any of the posts load. Do I need to specify a location? Or is it errors in the code?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is wrong. Try

```
$('#colorbox_test').colorbox({width: 500, height: 600});
```

You'll also want to get familiar with your browser's [javascript console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) for debugging things in the future.

Comment: I substituted that part in the function. It didn't work. Maybe it's the javascript and colorbox libraries paths?

Never used the console before; glad you mentioned it. I see it spots some errors:
- Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead
- TypeError: $ is not a function
- Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.

are they related? @cpilko

Comment: @RodrigoCardoso: The `$ is not a function` error is a killer in jQuery. The console should give you the file and line where the error occurs.

Comment: Also, take a look at [the proper way to use `$` in a noConflict wrapper](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers)

Comment: Got it. All errors indicated in the console are now clean. But I don't get a display of a pop up box with the colorbox content when I load a post yet. This is what I have now:
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      jQuery('#colorbox_test').colorbox({width: 500, height: 600});
 });
    </script>

Comment: Forgot to tell, @cpilko , I'm adding this code before the /head tag in my header.php. I'm not sure it's the best place to put it neither. I'll search for examples of how to apply this colorbox plugin in wordpress and maybe I detect something